# TypeScript cast as Partial<T> but keys must exist

Tags: typescript

<strike>I'm in need of two utility types: one subset of a type with matching value types and one that only needs the keys to exist in the other type.

I came up with the following which seems ok at first glance but I can't help but wonder if I'm doing something that is already built into TS (v4.7).</strike>

**Update:**
The problem why I was working on this was not with the type itself but with casting. Casting `{ nammme: 'John' as any } as Partial<Person>` works, which I want to prevent. I need to override the type of some properties (but preferably not all).

```
// This works...
const fields: Partial<DbUser> = {
  organizationId: FieldValue.delete() as any,
  groups: FieldValue.delete() as any,
};

return getFirestore()
  .collection(constants.dbCollections.users)
  .doc(context.auth.uid)
  .update(fields);

// This allows typos...
return getFirestore()
  .collection(constants.dbCollections.users)
  .doc(context.auth.uid)
  .update({
    organizationId: FieldValue.delete() as any,
    groups: FieldValue.delete() as any,
    typoooo: 1 as any,
} as Partial<DbUser>);
```

Code example

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

export type KeysIn<T> = {
  [key in keyof Partial<T>]: any;
};

export type MustContainKeyButTypeOfKeyCanBeOverwritten<T> = unknown; // ?

// Valid: Key exists in Person
const valid1: KeysIn<Person> = {
  name: 0,
};

// Valid: Key exists in Person and type matches
const valid2: Partial<Person> = {
  name: '',
};

// Invalid: Key does not exist in Person
const invalid1: KeysIn<Person> = {
  x: true,
};

// Invalid: Key exists in Person but type does not match
const invalid2: Partial<Person> = {
  name: 0,
};

// Invalid: Key does not exist in Person
const invalid3: Partial<Person> = {
  x: true,
};

// Typo with cast to any
const invalid4: KeysIn<Person> = {
  namessss: '' as any,
};

const invalid5 = {
  namessss: '' as any,
} as Partial<Person>; // Why is this valid?

const invalid6 = {
  namessss: '' as any,
} as KeysIn<Person>; // Why is this valid? I need this to be invalid

const idealExample: MustContainKeyButTypeOfKeyCanBeOverwritten<Person> = {
  name: 1 as any, // Allowed type override
  aggggggge: 1, // Typo, invalid
  age: '2', // Wrong type, invalid
};
```

Can I override only certain keys with new types while preventing typos?

<sup>[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subset-utitly-type?file=index.ts)</sup>

Comment: what's wrong with `export type Subset<T> = Partial<T>;` and `export type KeysIn<T> = keyof Subset<T>;`? how do you want to use `KeysIn`?

Comment: I somehow thought Partial allowed additional properties to be defined, I was wrong. So type Subset is not needed. KeysIn would be the same as Partial but without the need to match the type of the key. `PartialAny` maybe?

Comment: Partial allows typos when using `as`, that was the real problem. Updated the question.

Comment: I don't think type assertions is the right tool for this. What is wrong with using `.update(fields)`?

Comment: It seems more lengthy than necessary, but it is ok.

Comment: On the other hand, the second option should work without the use of `as Partial<DbUser>`. Doesn't that work?

Comment: What second option? Only the very first example of code works as I want (preventing typos but overriding type).

Comment: Like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAbnyiIYsIFcSAjBFgF8WuCAA8wyeMCihIUANIQQiAJKoAPABUAfJhysA2gGtlUelFMhkAM1hFptIgBttOgLqUiqEEJEBjNGooLjAAEyJgaCwACiJKGAdgJ1c4JDQdAEpMPWxBXFxQiKiY7GIySgAiAEFKgBo2DkoARga5ZCr-SsFMoA

Answer (score 0):

`Partial` does what you want out of `Subset`.

```
export type Subset<T> = Partial<T>;
```

For `KeysIn` I think your definition makes sense, an alternative is the following.

```
export type KeysIn<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, any>>;
```

Comment: Your `KeysIn` does not convert the type to any, it seems to behave the same as `Partial`

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood you. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized the problem was with casting which behaves different than I expected. Can you check the updated question? I'm looking something along the lines of `invalid5` and 6 in terms of syntax that would actually prevent typos.